# User change password on fileserver

Tags: windows-7, passwords, smb

Is it possible for a user to change his or her password on a fileserver with only SMB access? I have a fileserver that many people use. Everyone has the default password. I would like them to change their password, but I don't want them to come to me and have me change it on the fileserver. I would like them to change it somehow in their own Windows interface.

Answer (score 1):

PsPasswd can do what you want but explaining to the end users how to do this might not be suitable, its a tool designed for administrators.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897543.aspx

Comment: PsPasswd may be the best solution wrapped in a GUI for the end users. It knows their username. All they need to do is type their old and new password and then it will run the PsPasswd command without their knowledge of the internals.